# make apache_request_headers optional parameter in php

Tags: php

I am creating web services and i want to make "apache_request_headers" optional parameter in php
Right now if i am not entering "Token" parameter then i am getting error "undefined index Token"
How can i do this ? Here is my code

```
$tokens = apache_request_headers();
            $token = $tokens['Token'];
            if (empty($token)) {
                $responseJSON = array("Status" => false, "Result" => "Please enter token");
                header("content-type:application/json");
                $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
                echo $response;
            } else {
            //my code
            }
```

Comment: you can directly check for token `$tokens['Token']` in if condition

Comment: @DhavalPurohit: Sir, i just want "Notice" should not come if i forget to enter "Token", only error message should come like "please enter token", but right now i am getting notice if i am not enter Token

Comment: yes that's why you have to put condition on `$tokens['Token']`, if you forgot to put the token then `$tokens` doen't have the `Token` index. That's why you are getting the notice.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit: sir what should i do now ? what is the solution ?

Comment: _“what is the solution ?”_ - to realize which of those lines _causes_ the notice in the first place. PHP has mentioned file and line number in it, so what more info do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can prevent the notice.

```
$tokens = apache_request_headers();
//Edited code here
$token = !empty($tokens['Token']) ? $tokens['Token'] : "";
if (empty($token)) {
    $responseJSON = array("Status" => false, "Result" => "Please enter token");
    header("content-type:application/json");
    $response = json_encode($responseJSON);
    echo $response;
} else {
    //my code
}
```